# Angular: How to send data from a button to a service?

Tags: angular

I have a button in my header that enables changing my app's language. I want the selected language to be available to all components via a service. I know how to send data from a service to a component ("consume a service") but I can't figure out how to send the data from the button to the service.

Here's the button:

```js
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button (click)="change_L1_Language('en-US')">English<img width="50" alt="Flag of the United States" src="../assets/images/flags/us-flag.svg"></button>
    <button (click)="change_L1_Language('es')">Español<img width="50" alt="Flag of Spain" src="../assets/images/flags/es-flag.svg"></button>
    <button (click)="change_L1_Language('zh')">中文<img width="50" alt="Flag of China" src="../assets/images/flags/ch-flag.svg"></button>
    <button (click)="change_L1_Language('jp')">日本人<img width="50" alt="Flag of Japan" src="../assets/images/flags/jp-flag.svg" class="flag-border"></button>
  </mat-menu>
```

The controller handles the click:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageService } from '../language.service';

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  language: string = 'en-US';
  newLanguage: string = 'en-US';
  @Output() changeLanguageData: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

changeLanguage(newLanguage) {
    console.log(this.language);
    switch (true) {
      case (newLanguage === 'en-US'):
      this.language = 'en-US';
      break;

      case (newLanguage === 'es'):
      this.language = 'es';
      break;

      case (newLanguage === 'zh'):
      this.language = 'zh';
      break;

      case (newLanguage === 'jp'):
      this.language = 'jp';
      break;

      default:
      console.log("Error in switch-case.");
    }
    console.log(this.language);
    this.changeLanguageData.emit(this.language); // send data to parent
    this.LanguageService.changeLanguage().subscribe(); // receives data from a service, doesn't send data
  }
```

The controller is hooked up to `LanguageService` (a service) but the controller can only consume data from the service, it can't feed data to the service.

The controller also has an `Event Emitter` to send data to a parent component. This can't send data to a service because the service doesn't have an `.html` template for the link between components.

Looking at the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), it shows how components *within a family* can communicate via a service: [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). If I change this to

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

will this service provide the data to all components in my app?

The documentation also shows three methods for sending data from a parent component to the child component, which won't work because my service isn't a child of my component.

The documentation shows three methods for sending data from a child to a parent. The method I'm familiar with [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) with an `EventEmitter` won't work because the service doesn't have an `.html` template to link the components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the service as a dependency like:

**TS**:

```
constructor(private languageService: LanguageHandler) { }
```

Then you can use it in your component to change stuff on click:

**HTML**:

```
<button (click)="changeLanguage("en-US")>Change to English</button>
```

**TS**:

```
changeLanguage(languageToChangeTo) {
  languageService.currentLanguage = languageToChangeTo;
}
```

Comment: That works if I change the last line to ```this.languageService.changeLanguage(language);```

Comment: It depends on how your service is written. If it's writtin in method change style your line is correct, but if you use getter and setter, my line would be correct, I think it's quite personal preference on what you use.